# Powershell: Hiding columns and bordering cells in Excel

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-ise

I've been diving into how Powershell can use Excel as a COM object, have most of it down but there are two things I'd like to be able to do that I haven't been able to find anywhere, hoping someone can help.

1/ Would like to be able to script hiding a range of columns in the generated Excel spreadsheet.

2/ Would like to be able to have Excel add a border around all cells in the script as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the code? Or use VBA!!

Comment: I don't have code for these, that's the point. I'm looking for someone that may have these figured out. I can post the other code I'm using in my script for Excel if that would help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hiding a column:

Here is an example that you can adapt. This is hiding the first column in the active work sheet.

```
$file = "C:\Users\Micky\Desktop\not locked.xlsx"

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel")|Out-Null
$excel = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
$excel.Visible = $true 
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$ws = $wb.ActiveSheet
$c = $ws.Columns
$c.Item(1).hidden = $true
```

Cell border:
For the example I use a double border and apply to the first cell, A1.

The XlLineStyle Enum can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241348(v=office.12).aspx)

```
$xlDouble = -4119
$item = $ws.Range("A1")
$item.Borders.LineStyle = $xlDouble
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That definitely gives me something to work with. Much appreciated!